# .htaccess rewrite rule, change URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm looking for the following to change the URL with two variables in a .htaccess file, from:

```
domain.com/folder/a123/url/index.php
domain.com/otherfolder/a321/url/index.php
```

to:

```
domain.com/folder/url/index.php
domain.com/otherfolder/url/index.php
```

I would prefer it in a single line .htaccess RewriteRule, if possible.

"folder" and "otherfolder" are the only two "folder names" and "a123"/"a321" can be anything starting with "a" and ending with random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in one with just one rule using this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)/a[0-9]*/url/index.php$ /$1/url/index.php [R=301,NC]
```

But if you want to redirect all pages and not only `index.php` then use this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/a[0-9]*/url/(.*)$ /$1/url/$2 [R=301,NC]
```

Also, if you want to rewrite the URLs instead of redirect them change `[R=301,NC]` to `[NC]`.

Note that if you have that pattern in other URLs this rule will also apply, for example it will also redirect `domain.com/adifferentfolder/a567/url/index.php` to `domain.com/adifferentfolder/url/index.php`, if you have those type URLs and don't want to redirect them you need to use two rules instead:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/a[0-9]*/url/(.*)$ /folder/url/$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^otherfolder/a[0-9]*/url/(.*)$ /otherfolder/url/$1 [R=301,NC]
```